# Class property not assigned inside closure in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble assigning a value to a property inside my Swift class. The property prints out fine inside the class but returns `nil` when accessed externally when calling the class method that assigns the property in the main viewController. Here is my class definition.

```
import Foundation

class NetworkConnection {

    var jsonObj: AnyObject?

    func makeHTTPRequest(data: String, location: String, completion: (jsonData: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void){

        var jsonData: AnyObject!

        let post: NSString = "data=\(data)"
        let url = NSURL(string: location)!
        let postData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let postLength = String(postData.length)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { urlData, response, responseError in

            if let receiveData = urlData {

                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!

                if 200..<300 ~= res.statusCode {
                    do {
                        jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receiveData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.init(rawValue:0))

                        completion(jsonData: jsonData, error: nil)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        let returnedError = NSError(domain: "validateUser", code: 3, userInfo: [
                            "title": "Made up title",
                            "message": "This is a messsage",
                            "cause": error
                            ])
                        completion(jsonData: nil, error: returnedError)
                    }
                }else{
                    let returnedError = NSError(domain: "validateUser", code: 1, userInfo: [
                        "title": "Second made up title",
                        "message": "This is another message"
                        ])
                    completion(jsonData: nil, error: returnedError)
                }
            }else{

                var userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [
                    "title": "Third made up title",
                    "message": "This is yet another message"
                ]
                if let error = responseError {
                    userInfo["message"] = error.localizedDescription
                    userInfo["cause"] = error
                }
                let returnedError = NSError(domain: "validateUser", code: 2, userInfo: userInfo)
                completion(jsonData: nil, error: returnedError)
            }


        }
        task.resume()

    }

    func validateUser(location: String, username: String, password: String) {

        let data = "&username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

        self.makeHTTPRequest(data, location: location) { jsonData, error in

            if let json = jsonData {

                self.jsonObj = json


                print(self.jsonObj)   // This shows property was assigned without errors

            }else{
                let userInfo = error!.userInfo
                let title = userInfo["title"] as! String
                let message = userInfo["message"] as! String
                print(title)
                print(message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function that I call the `validatUser()` method in my viewController

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

        let service = NetworkConnection()
        service.validateUser("http://myPhpServiceLink.com/mobile.login.php", username: usernameField.text!, password: passwordField.text!)

        if let serviceObj = service.jsonObj {

            print("success loading object \(serviceObj)")

        } else {

            print("error loading object from call \(service.jsonObj)")

        }
}
```

Here is the JSON data to be returned by PHP.

```
{"id":"1","username":"admin","message":"User is valid","error":null}
```

The line: `print("service object = \(self.jsonObj)")` 
prints out the following in the console:

```
service object = Optional({
     error = "<null>";
     id = 1;
     message = "User is valid";
     username = admin;
})
```

But I get the "error loading object from call nil" from the `@IBAction` function. I've looked everywhere to find out why the property always returns `nil` when called externally and it is also hard to articulate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is due to your http request being performed in the background.
`if let serviceObj = service.jsonObj` is being executed before your `validateUser` method is completed.  you need to rewrite `valdiateUser to take a completion handler.

Comment: Dude! Thank you! You saved my sanity. I didn't think that I needed another completion closure because the validateUser() was a completion closure for makeHTTPRequest(). I guess you should do it on all funcitons lol.